# Facebook MultiLogin in Android Webview

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I have an embedded webview in my app. I have to show Facebook's new MultiLogin at one point during which the popup like window which appears when trying to login does not appear. The facebook login opens up in a new window. Once I successfully login, I'm taken to a blank window. How do I overcome this? Even the cancel button in the login page does not do anything. If I open this url in Android's basic browser, the popup appears perfectly fine and everything works as intended.

The Multilogin that I'm referring to is like the comments window that you find in this page.

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/03/07/comments-box-google-twitter/

I have overridden the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method for my webview as,

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
 return false;
}
```

Can someone help me with this? Apologies if this has already been resolved, but I could not find the post anywhere.

-Hari

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question. But if you want to close WebView in specific url, you can use shouldOverrideUrlLoading like this.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if( url.equals("process-done-url") {
       myWebView.close(); //just psuedocode. I'm not sure exact method
       return true; // don't handle url in other place. 
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: No. The issue is that when I open the url in an embedded webview, as the one mentioned above, and use the multilogin feature from Facebook to comment (This is available in the url that I've mentioned), the login window has to be a popup window. But it opens up as a new page in the webview and so the login and other actions are not working as intended. If I open this url in android's browser then the popups are working. My question was how to get this working in a embedded browser. Sorry if I was not clear in my question.