# How to accept multiple logins on android application? (Different WebViews)

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, caching, webview

I'm trying to create an application that allows the user to login to multiple accounts using different webviews.

Scenario:

There are 2 webviews (Webview_1 & Webview_2)
Both webviews load the URL: facebook.com

However, if I login on webview_1 with the facebook account (Sarah John),
Webview_2 automatically loads that account as well.

How can I prevent this?

I've found some old answers from the year 2014 but those solutions are no longer valid.

Comment: which 2014 answer are you looking at why is it no longer valid? This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26525546/1862452 seems promising just from my knowledge with webviews. Android cookies are shared between multiple webviews and if you want to do multiple logins, you have to manage the cookies yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. In the onPageFinished method, what would be the condition?